# Magento 2.4.4 shipping delivery methods not visible

Tags: magento2

Magento admin configuration sales is missing Delivery Methods. [image: No delivery methods]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the Magenx script used to install Magento disables module-ups and module-usps within composer_replace. Disabling "replace section" in composer.json and running composer update will enable the modules.